# selenium cannot send keys to input box

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to login with seleinum automatically. I've used

1. driver.execute_script
2. driver.find_element_by_css_selector
3. driver.find_element_by_xpath

.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager import chrome

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://naco999.com/")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#login_id').send_keys("id")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#login_pw").send_keys("pw")
```

But none of these seems to work. How can I?

Comment: https://naco999.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 elements matching `#login_id` css_selector.
Try using this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".header-one #login_id").send_keys("id")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".header-one #login_pw").send_keys("pw")
```

Also, you should add a wait to send the text when the elements are loaded.
Like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager import chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install())
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://naco999.com/")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".header-one #login_id"))).send_keys("id")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".header-one #login_pw"))).send_keys("pw")
```

Comment: Exactly! I was just going to write that!

Comment: So the selenium sended keys to another element?

Comment: Sure, it's simple :)

Comment: And that element is not actually visible here

Comment: Then, how can I know there's three same css_selector?

Comment: Within the dev tools you put this locator and see how many matches are there. You can go thru them with arrows there.

Comment: Can I ask you what is .header-one ?

Comment: Class name of some element there. So that element with id = `ogin_id` that is inside element with class name = `header-one` gives unique locator of desired element

Comment: This did not work for me; I get a `TimeoutException`.

Comment: And I only found one occurrence of #login_id.

Comment: This is what I see in dev tools with my browser. maybe the page is changing according to IP address? However the topic starter seems to be satisficed with this solution

Comment: options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('window-size=1920,1080')

add this, it would work. I don't know why.